# Expand/collapse all grouped items in views of a page

Tags: javascript, list-view, jquery

Is there a way to add a button to a SharePoint 2010 page to expand all grouped items in all the list views on the page? This is the first (top) level grouping only, not the second level. These are simple (standard) list views created via the web UI, where we've grouped  items on one or two columns. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is possible. You can use some javascript to do that. Here is a post about this.
http://alectang.com/blog/archive/2010/09/09/easy-expand-or-collapse-sharepoint-list-in-group-by-view.aspx

The trick is to find the little minus button and then click it:

```
function expandGroups() { 
    $("img[src*='plus.gif']:visible").parent().click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, SPSinan. What if I have two levels of grouping and need all to be expanded?

Comment: Found the answer: Just remove the `:visible` from the statement and it works on the hidden grouped elements too :)

Comment: Tried this in SP 2010. Could not get it to work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Clem Do you get an error message or something?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with SP2010.
Any ideas with SP 2010
Thanks

Comment: I think this might work only if the groups have already been expanded once.  The content in the groups doesn't load into the html until SharePoint's `ExpGroupRenderData` function is called by the user clicking on the groups to expand them.  That is why this doesn't appear to work in 2010.

Answer (score 1):

one way for making sure all 3 levels are expanded

```
<script src="https://portal/SiteAssets/jsLibrary/jquery.1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

$(document).ready(function () {
     // Wait until SP.JS has loaded before calling expandAll
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(expandAll, "sp.js");
});

    function expandAll(){
        //for making sure all 3 levels are expanded
        $("img[src$='plus.gif']").parent().trigger("click");
        $("img[src$='plus.gif']").parent().trigger("click");
        $("img[src$='plus.gif']").parent().trigger("click");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function expandAll() {
        $('img[alt="expand"]').click();
    }

    function collapseAll() {
        $('img[alt="collapse"]').click();
    }

    var expandButton = "<a href='#' onClick="

    +'"' + "this.href='javascript:expandAll()'"

    + '">&nbsp;<img title="expand all groups" style="border:none;" alt="expand all" src="/_layouts/images/collapseplus.gif"></a>';

    var collapseButton = "<a href='#' onClick="

    +'"' + "this.href='javascript:collapseAll()'"

    + '">&nbsp;<img title="expand all groups" style="border:none;" alt="collapse all" src="/_layouts/images/collapseminus.gif"></a>';

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".div").append(expandButton).append(collapseButton); // select div where you would like to place the icons.
    });
</script>
```